# rails view with bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models. parent, and child. each parent has many children

```
#parent model
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
end

#child model
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I want to use bootstrap `nav-tabs`, each tab should show parent's children only. any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First thing do select when id in `parent` table = `children.parent.id`

   - in `ParentController`

```
@parent_children = Parent.select('DISTINCT name').joins(:children).where('id' = 'children.parent.id')
```

- `@parent_children` return unique name of parent has children

Comment: thanks, I have found another way, thank you for your help. @TalaatMagdy